# Google Analytics API disable robots and "spiders" traffic by API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

At Google Analytics in the *Admin section* -> *View Settings*, we can check the “*exclude all hits from known bots and spiders*”, this is exclude bot traffic from Google Analytics.
But how to do this with API?
I tried to find information about this in the documentation, but I didn't find anything.
Maybe someone has already encountered this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Never seen that filter being used in the API, but that piece of functionality is pretty trivial really.

We typically just reimplement that logic after pulling the data in. The logic looks at the user agent dimension for known bot signatures and that's it.

And you do want to have some control over what a bot is and is not rather than relying on a complete black box.

Comment: You determine whether it is a bot or a user by the parameter ga:browser  ?
https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/dimensions-metrics-explorer/platform-or-device/#browser

Comment: no, useragent typically is a combo of four dimensions: browser, browser version, OS and OS version. We just shove it into a custom dimension as `navigator.userAgent`. Don't want to rely on Google's dimension processing for this.